# Using grep to filter out "permission denied" files?

Tags: bash, grep, cygwin

I'm trying to use the find command to find an excel file.  However, I only want the files that DO NOT have "permission denied".

So, I tried the following:

```
find . -name "excel" | grep "!(permission denied)"
```

However, this doesn't work.  I'm using grep version 4.5.12 on Cygwin.  Why doesn't this command work?  And, is there an easier way to do this?  Ideally, the solution would involve `find` and `grep` because I'm very familiar with those commands.

Thanks.

Comment: Error messages are reported on standard error, not standard output, and only standard output goes down the pipe to `grep`.  You also need to use `grep -v`; the `!` doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I see the  duplicate.  What is the equivalent  on Mac OSx terminal?

Comment: `find . -name "excel" 2>/dev/null` is easiest; it sends all error messages to `/dev/null` so you won't see permission denied.  Failing that, follow the other question — whichever solution you prefer.  Which works for you depends on whether you're writing a script for anyone anywhere in the world to use at any time under any circumstances, or whether you're writing for yourself — and whether your `find` supports the relevant options.  (BSD `find`, and hence `find` on Mac OS X, does not support `-readable`.)